# Cron Job on 1and1

Tags: php, cron

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I've been working on this for days, looked at a whole host of documentation, but I can't seem to get it right.

I'm trying to run a php script as a cron job, the file is contained on a server under the following address:

`mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/cronfile.php`

I understand the numeric vales or `*` that I need to enter at the beginning of the line of code but it's what comes after that which I'm struggling with.

I'm using a Linux server with 1and1, and at the moment my line of code reads:
`* * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /development/cronfile.php`. I've tried changing it to `usr/bin/php`, than changing the second part of the code to `mapmyfinds/development/cronfile.php`, all without any success.

I just wonder whether someone may be able shed some light on this please so I can get the job to run correctly.

Many thanks

Comment: Follow 1and1's documentation on the matter: http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/cron_jobs/3.html

Comment: Hi @Nick, yes I've followed the documentation from 1and1, and I can get their sample script to run. However I'm not sure how I change the script to run from my server folders. I've tried applying the same logic as per their example and I can't get it to work. Kind regards

Comment: Q and link in accepted answer helped me a lot. Got my 1and1 crontab up and running now. I owe you a beer. +1'd

Answer (score 2):

Did you specify the user you want to run the script with ?

The correct syntax is

```
*  *  * * *    root    /usr/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php
```

For every minute, runned as root.

Also, like lexalizer proposed, try running your script manually from the shell, to see what is it outputting.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying. No I haven't said which user the script is ttached to. Basically the php script sending an email to all members whom have 7 days left on their subscription. All the details concerning who the email goes to is contained within the software application. Kind regards

Comment: By the user, I meant the `unix` user, not the user you want to send the email to. In your Apache configuration you can see under what user it is running. Just specify that same user in your crontab.

Comment: Hi, I think I've got the unix user. Could you tell me please, where I would incorporate that into my code? Kind regards

Comment: Just before the command you want to execute in your crontab file. Also, check in /var/log/syslog to see if there is any relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to get the full production PHP path by using the output from phpinfo(); Also put the full path to the cronfile.php file, not just the relative one.

Finally, before running the cron job, try to run that command manually to see what it does/outputs.

Comment: Hi many thanks for replying to my post. Forgive me for asking, I'm very new to this, could you perhaps be a little more specific please. I've run the `phpinfo`, but I'm not quite sure what I'm looking for. Kind regards

Comment: As far as I know, from 1and1 you can access the shell. See the help here: http://faq.1and1.com/web_space__access/secure_shell_access_ssh/index.html In the phpinfo() output you can look for the php executable path and use that as part of your cront command. Alternatively you can type which php while logged into your shell. After you log into your shell you can also test the cron command to see if it's correct before setting it to run as a cron. To test it simply execute the command in the console.

Comment: Hi @lexalizer, many thanks for this. I'm actually running the Shell access at the moment, and this is where I'm trying to create the cron job from. As I said, it's just proving difficult in getting the correct filepath. From what I've read if I type `pwd` this gives me the start of the filepath. In my case I receive `/kunden/homepages/2/d000000/htdocs` The 1and1 docs then say to use `whereis php` which locates the php, and in my case I receive `usr/bin/php`. I thought that if I added them togteher and added the rest of my file path to the end it would work. But unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Actually here is a good tutorial about setting up cron jobs on 1and1 servers: http://faq.1and1.com/scripting_languages_supported/cron_jobs/index.html This should get you off the ground quickly.